# Raspberry Pi Java Shutdown hook

Tags: java, jar, raspberry-pi, shutdown-hook

I have a Raspberry Pi running Java 1.8.0 and a file called test.jar. When I run the code and then stop the program with Ctrl+Z the Shutdown hook does not run but when I run the code on windows and stop it, the shutdown hook will work.

How can I fix this, Thanks

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread()   //Add shutdown code
        {
            public void run()
            {
                System.out.println("Shutdown");
            }
        });

        while(true) { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use infinite loop in constructor is pain... Try exclude while loop in some method.

Comment: Are you attempt press Ctrl+C in Rasberry instead Ctrl+Z?

Comment: that works, thanks. is there anything too different in using Ctrl+C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a linux terminal, ctrl-z sends a `SIGSTOP` to the foreground process. This is one of two signals (the other being `SIGKILL`) that you *cannot handle* in your process. That means that java has no way to run any code in response to the signal.

However, `SIGSTOP` doesn't end the process anyway, it simply pauses it. You can continue it by sending a `SIGCONT` signal, which can be achieved in your shell by using the `fg` command.

Try using `ctrl-c` instead to end your program, and it ought to work (since that will send a `SIGINT` instead, which can be handled).